# vagrant variables in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile, dockerfile

I use Vagrant and Docker to create web environments.

I have a Vagrantfile with the following code in my "web.vm.provider "docker" do |d|" section :

```
d.env = {
    DRUSH_VERSION:"7.0.0"
}
```

Then in my Dockerfile, for testing, I have :

```
RUN echo $DRUSH_VERSION > /d.txt
```

But unfortunately, I have no value in $DRUSH_VERSION...
Am I missing something ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

With docker 1.9.x you now have the ability to pass build variables into docker build, with the new ARG instruction.

https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15182